# In Rails 3, I'm using the jQuery Tokenize plugin but the form submits the value, not the id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I love [this](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) plugin, I've used this in PHP with ease, but I'm trying now in Rails 3 and for some reason when the form gets submitted, it's not submitting the id of the selected item, it's submitting the actual value.  I've even printed out the JSON to make sure that the data is being fed to the input field properly and it's showing the ID and the VALUE.

Any ideas on why this is happening.  I've been thinking that maybe I need to add a custom javascript call for the onBlur, but I've never had to do that prior to this.  Anyone have any other suggestions, or even a totally different way to accomplish an autocomplete in Rails with multiple selections?

I appreciate any help that you can give me, thanks!!  And yes, I know the input isn't cleaned :)

```
  def autocomplete
    autolist = []
    sql = "SELECT id,username from users WHERE username LIKE '" + params[:q] + "%'"
    result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
    result.each { |field| autolist.push( {"id" => field[0], "name" => field[1]} ) }
    render :json => autolist, :layout => false
  end
```

The code for the form:

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <tr>
        <% if @reply_to.nil? %>
        <td width="100"><p class="labels">To:</p></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :to %>
            <%= error_message_on @message, :to %></td>
        <% else %>
      <td width="100">To: <%= @message.to %><%= f.hidden_field :to, :value => @message.to  %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <% if @reply_to.nil? %>
    <td width="100"><p class="labels">Patient:</p></td>
    <td><%= f.collection_select :patient_id, Patient.find_all_by_user_id(current_user), :id, :last_name %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :patient_id %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td width="100">Patient: <%= Patient.find(@message.patient_id).last_name %><%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value => @message.patient_id  %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <% if @reply_to.nil? %>
    <td width="100"><p class="labels">Subject:</p></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :subject %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td width="100">Subject: <%= @message.subject %><%= f.hidden_field :subject, :value => @message.subject  %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="100" valign="top"><p class="labels">Message:</p></td>
      <td><%= f.text_area :body %>
            <%= error_message_on @message, :body %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td width="100" valign="top"><p class="labels">Attachment:</p></td>
      <td><%= f.file_field :attachment %><%= error_message_on @message, :attachment %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><%= submit_tag "Send" %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function($) {
    $("#message_to").tokenInput("/users/1/friends/autocomplete", {
                hintText: "Type in the name of a colleague",
                noResultsText: "No results",
                searchingText: "Searching..."
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't we be looking at the code for the form?

Comment: Surely - http://pastie.org/1452530

Comment: Can you post your associated javascript?

Comment: just posted it dmarkow - sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Your text field and your hidden field need different names.

Comment: what do you mean the hidden field and text field?  which fields are you referring to?

Comment: You have a `f.text_field :to` and a `f.hidden_field :to` -- both using the same id. However, since these are under separate if/else conditions, this shouldn't be the problem.